# Rotating a log with date included

Tags: ubuntu, logs

How do I setup logrotate to rotate openerp-server.log into openerp-server-YY-MM-DD.log?

Comment: This question isn't too broad, it's about a specific feature of logrotate.

Comment: i have to rotate openerp-server.log to openerp-server-YY-MM-DD.log..eg:it should be look like this       openerp-server-2015-02-06.log

Comment: do you got me what i have said before comment.

Comment: @user102138 I think he's asking for your current `logrotate.conf` settings for this log file.

Comment: after logfile rotated it should be appear like this  openerp-server-2015-02-06.log

Answer (score 4):

Geez someone has really gone on a tear voting to close questions without even attempting to ask for clarification.

To answer your question, though you want to look at `dateext`. For example:

```
/var/log/yum.log {
    missingok
    notifempty
    size 30k
    yearly
    create 0600 root root
    dateext
}
```

Which results in:

```
[root@xxx01 ~]# ll /var/log/yum.log*
-rw------- 1 root root    0 Feb  6 08:39 /var/log/yum.log
-rw------- 1 root root 4060 Jan  1  2014 /var/log/yum.log-20140101.gz
-rw------- 1 root root 1383 Jan  1 03:35 /var/log/yum.log-20150101.gz
```

If you want to change the date format you can use the `dateformat` directive.

Answer (score 1):

```
/var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
 {
        weekly
        rotate 5
        copytruncate
        missingok
        ifempty
        postrotate
                /etc/init.d/odoo-server force-reload > /dev/null
                cat /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log >> /var/log/odoo/odoo-server-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log
        endscript
 }
```

Comment: This won't work as well because you're actually copying a more or less empty log (since the log is truncated as part of the rotate) and the actual log is still going to be named `odoo-server.log.1` `odoo-server.log.2` etc etc. This is why the `dateext` is used for what you're wanting. You also probably want to change `ifempty` to be `notifempty` otherwise you'll have even more empty logs.

Comment: Is the command for restarting ODoo server?

```/etc/init.d/odoo-server force-reload > /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

```
/var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log {
daily
copytruncate
create 644 harmony-4 harmony-4
dateext
dateformat -%Y-%m-%d
rotate 5
extension .log
}
```